# what is the setter method to change value of custom attribute of Item class?

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute, magento-1

I want to modify value of custom attribute of custom attribute set in observer.
I can modify some core attribute which is having setter method like 
                $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
but I could not found any setter method for custom attribute.
I tried with like $item->setData('voucher_value', 259);
Also tried like

```
              $item->addOption(array(
                "product_id" => $item->getProduct()->getId(),
                "product" => $item->getProduct(),
                "code" => "voucher_value",
                "value" => serialize($results)
            ));
```

But could not set value. 
Please Help.

Comment: i guess you can give a try like this $item->setVoucherValue(259), I  guess your custm attribute is voucher_value

Comment: I tried this but not working. voucher_value is attribute of 'Voucher' attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use setters and getters thanks to the magic methods of `Varien_Object`, or set it directly with `$item->setData('voucher_value', 259)` if you prefer. Attribute sets do not matter here.

But quote items do not automatically inherit product attributes. It's not clear from the question what exactly you are trying to achieve, but this tutorial should help you: http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/